# Rails unpermitted parameter when nesting forms multiple levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, a `Property` has_many `units` and each unit belongs to a Property. A `Unit`  has_one `unit_amenity` and a `unit_amenity` belongs to a unit.  The issue is that I need to nest the unit_amenity form which is 2 levels down in the new property form and I'm getting an `Unpermitted parameter` error.  I also see just "unit_amenity"=>{"heat"=>"1"} in the logs instead of "unit_amenity_attributes"=>{"heat"=>"1"}.

Property.rb

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :units, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

Unit.rb

```
class Unit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property

  has_one :unit_amenity, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unit_amenity, allow_destroy: true 
end
```

Unit_amenity.rb

```
class UnitAmenity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

I have nested the unit_amenity params within the unit params in properties_controller.rb

```
    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def property_params
      params.require(:property).permit(:city, :state, :zip_code, 
        units_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :unit_number, :bedrooms, :bathrooms, :property_id,
          unit_amenity_attributes: [ :id, :_destroy, :unit_id, :heat, :air_conditioning ] ])
      end
    end
```

The form has a nested fields_for for unit_amenity

```
    <%= form_with(model: property) do |form| %>
        <div class="col-span-6">
          <%= form.label :city %>
          <%= form.text_field :city %>  
        </div>
        ....

        <%= form.fields_for :unit_amenity do |amenity_field| %>
          <div>
            <%= amenity_field.check_box :heat, class: '', type: 'checkbox', id: 'heat' %>
            <%= amenity_field.label :heat, class: "text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" %>                   
          </div>                
           ....
       <% end %> 
    <% end %>
```

The `new` action of the properties_conroller.rb

```
  def new
    @property = Property.new
    
    units = @property.units.build # has_many association
    units.build_unit_amenity # has_one association
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the calls to fields for:

```
<%= form_with(model: property) do |form| %>
  # ...
  <%= form.fields_for :units do |unit_field| %>
    <%= unit_field.fields_for :unit_amenity do |amenity_field| %>
       # ...   
   <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

Aparat from that you should also remove `property_id` and `unit_id` from the parameters whitelist. Never have the "parent id" in the params whitelist.

They are assigned when you create nested records and could actually be used to create records belonging to another property if a malicous user felt like it.